# in js libraries how can $.something (object) also be $("something") (a function)?

Tags: javascript, function, object, libraries

This may turn out to be a simple question with a very complex answer, or something very simple which I have just missed completely, but, in libraries like Prototype and jQuery etc., how can the `$` global variable be an object that contains functions, for example:

```
$.ajax.get(…);
```

and also a function itself, like:

```
$("…");
```

Any help, even a pointer to a more explanatory Web site would be brilliant, I'm just intrigued!

For example, if I created a function (`$`), that contained a child object (`ajax`) like:

```
var $ = function() {
    this.ajax = {};
    return this;
};
```

I could access the `ajax` object like `$().ajax`, but not like `$.ajax`, how do you get them both?

Comment: functions are first-class citizens in javascript. They can have their own properties, functions, and prototype.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In JavaScript, functions are Objects, and Objects may have properties, so it's just another wonderful part of the language!

```
var f = function(x) { return x; };
f.attr = "a";
f.attr; // => "a"
f(123); // => 123
```

Comment: Thanks @maerics, I know all functions are Objects, but how, for example would you go about coding such a thing? I'll update my question with an example.

Comment: @Jonathon: In anticipation of this follow-up I added an example already =)

Answer (score 3):

all javascript functions are javascript objects.

```
var obj = {};
var func = new function(){};

obj.property = "";
func.property = "";
```

you can learn all about it here: http://ejohn.org/apps/learn/#16

Answer (score 0):

```
var $ = (function () {

    var keys = { a: 1, b: 2, c: "Bob" },
        external_func = function (key, val) {
            if (val === undefined) { return keys[key]; }
            keys[key] = val;
            extend(external_func, { key : val });
        };

    function extend (obj, keys) {
        var key;
        for (key in keys) {
            if (keys.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                obj[key] = keys[key];
            }
        }
    }

    extend(external_func, keys);
    external_func.setKey = function (key, val) { keys[key] = val; this[key] = val; };
    return external_func;
}());
```

jQuery's a lot bigger than just this, but this might be an example of how you could build a system that saves keys and values, that you can read either as a function call or as a property.

For example, if keys held a breakdown of all queries in the URL, or held all cookies for the page, you could do something like:

Cookie("logged-in");
Cookie["logged-in"];
Cookie.username;

Query("page_name");
Query["page_name"];
Query.page_name;

You'd just have to be sure to treat it as read-only, unless either you use the function, use a `setCookie` method attached to the function, or you're targeting only browsers which support native getters and setters.